# Remove certain part from each line in notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Basically I have a huge text file formatted like this:

```
    496: 15580@plcstudents.org.au|valrh
    576: 186421@lizzy.com.au|$te
    731: 19carat@iinet.net.au|bghu78s
    2438: 5storm_shane@yahoo.com.au|hold
    3340: Aforalam@yahoo.com.au|khadija
```

I want to edit the list so after removal the list looks like this:

```
    15580@plcstudents.org.au|valrh
    186421@lizzy.com.au|$te
    19carat@iinet.net.au|bghu78s
    5storm_shane@yahoo.com.au|hold
    Aforalam@yahoo.com.au|khadija
```

So basically remove the numbers,the colon, and the space.

Comment: In Notepad++ find what `^\d+:\s*` replace with blank Never forget to check regular expression checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Find and replace with "" (i.e., leave the "replace with" field blank):

```
\d+:[ ]
```

- `\d` Matches a digit
- `+` Matches one or more of the previous item, in this case digits
- `:` Matches a colon
- `[ ]` Matches a space - NB You don't need the square brackets; I just wanted the space to be visible

In the future, you can find a lot of great info on regexes at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Search/Replace dialog.

Use `(\d+: )(.*)` as the value for "Find what:".

Use `\2` as "Replace with:"

Check the "Regular expression" item at the bottom left in the "Search Mode" box.

Input:

```
496: 15580@plcstudents.org.au|valrh
576: 186421@lizzy.com.au|$te
731: 19carat@iinet.net.au|bghu78s
2438: 5storm_shane@yahoo.com.au|hold
3340: Aforalam@yahoo.com.au|khadija
```

Output:

```
15580@plcstudents.org.au|valrh
186421@lizzy.com.au|$te
19carat@iinet.net.au|bghu78s
5storm_shane@yahoo.com.au|hold
Aforalam@yahoo.com.au|khadija
```

Answer (score 0):

If you alreay know how to user regular expression search on Notepad++, just use this:

([0-9])\w+:\s

If you whant know more see this: http://www.regexr.com/ and http://markantoniou.blogspot.com.br/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html